# Is there an easy way to calculate the graph edit distance of two graphs with a brut force algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

Without using the networkx built-in function, is there an easy brut force algorithm that calculates the graph edit distance between `G1` and `G2`?

I searched on the Internet, but I could only find hard optimal solutions

Comment: It is indeed a hard problem. But maybe your graphs fulfill certain conditions that make it easier?

Comment: Indeed, it would be for small graphs with not more than 4-5 edges I would say. This is why I'm seeking for a not too complex algorithm

Comment: Bidirectional breadth first search (on the graph of graphs) is what I would try.

Comment: How about this approximation of networkx: [`optimize_graph_edit_distance`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.similarity.optimize_graph_edit_distance.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Juan Carlos Ramirez reply (who gave a pseudo code of the algorithm), I finally implemented the ugly brutforce algorithm I was expecting. As mentionned in the conversation, it only deals with small graphs as the complexity is exponential. The following Python code uses:

1. `networkx`  (for graph manipulation)
2. `algorithmx`  (for graph    2D-rendering)

```
  from networkx.classes.function import nodes
  
  import algorithmx
  import networkx as nx
  from algorithmx.networkx import add_graph
  
  canvas1 = algorithmx.jupyter_canvas()
  canvas2 = algorithmx.jupyter_canvas()
  # Create a directed graph
  G1 = nx.Graph()
  G2 = nx.Graph()
  
  # G1.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (7, 4), (2, 7),(3, 7)])
  # G2.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 3), (3, 5)])
  
  G1.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (5, 4), (2, 5),(3, 5)])
  G2.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 3), (3, 1)])
  
  
  
  def graph_distance(G1, G2):
    tmp_graphs = []
    next_graphs = [G1]
    dist = 0
    nId = 1000
  
    while 1:
      print(dist)
      for graph in next_graphs:
        if nx.is_isomorphic(graph, G2): # Check isomorphism for each built graph
          return dist
  
  
        new_graph = graph.copy()
        new_graph.add_node(len(graph.nodes))
        tmp_graphs.append(new_graph) # Add one vertex (that will be connected to the rest of the graph in the next iterations)
  
        graph_copy = graph.copy()
        for node in graph.nodes : # Add edge
          for newNeighbour in graph.nodes :
            if not graph.has_edge(node, newNeighbour):
              new_graph = graph.copy()
              new_graph.add_edge(node, newNeighbour)
              tmp_graphs.append(new_graph)
        
        for node in graph.nodes : # Delete edge
          for newNeighbour in graph.nodes:
            if graph.has_edge(node, newNeighbour):
              new_graph = graph.copy()
              new_graph.remove_edge(node, newNeighbour)
              tmp_graphs.append(new_graph)
            
        for node in graph.nodes : # Delete vetex
          new_graph = graph.copy()
          new_graph.remove_node(node)
          tmp_graphs.append(new_graph)
  
      dist+=1
      next_graphs = tmp_graphs
      tmp_graphs = []
      
      
   
        
  print("Graph edit distance is:",graph_distance(G1, G2))
  add_graph(canvas1, G1)
  add_graph(canvas2, G2)

  canvas1
  # canvas2
```

Uncomment canvas1/canvas2 to display the one you want

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very inefficient process, but it does solve the problem. The idea will be to do a  Dijkstra-like shortest-path search from the "edit graph", where the nodes in the edit graph represent Graphs, there is an edge between two nodes `G_a`, `G_b` in an edit graph if there is an edit  that takes `G_a` to `G_b`. Note, you will need  you will need a function `is_isomorphic(Gx,Gy)` which tests whether `Gx` and `Gy` are isomorphic graphs (which you can check by checking all the node  permutations, again very costly).

The algorithm to find shortest edit distance would be as follows:

```
initialize: current_node as  G1,
            visited_nodes as G1,
            current_minimum_cost_dictionary={G1:0}
            #overload == for Graph Class so that G==F iff is_isomorphic(G,F)
while G2 not in visited nodes:
    cost = current_minimum_cost_dictionary[G2]
    neighbor_graphs_set = calculate_distinct_neighbor_nodes(current_node)
        for graph in neighbor_graphs_set:
            if graph not in visited_nodes:
                visited_nodes.push(graph)
                current_minimum_cost_dictionary[graph] = cost + 1
            else:
                current_minimum_cost_dictionary[graph] = min(cost + 1, current_minimum_cost_dictionary[graph])
    #set current_node to the Graph with the minimum value in current_minimum_cost
return current_minimum_cost_dictionary(G2)
```

`calculate_distinct_neighbor_nodes` returns the set of distinct graphs (up to isomorphism)that are neighbors of the input graph. two graphs x,y are neighbors if x can be obtained from y by 1 edit (or viceversa).

Comment: Thanks Juan Carlos! I did an implementation of your code that I'll post as a reply, and it fits your algorithm indeed! But it's probably more dirty :-)